# Logstash .raw Fields are not appearing in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Using ES 1.7 with Kibana 4 and Logstash 1.5

I'm using the Twitter Input and streaming from Twitter. Everything's working fine, but I can't find fields.raw (the fields before Logstash analyzes them, in other words when the fields and not_analyzed)

Why is that and how can I fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ES only fields appear. but if in Kibana field.raw doesn't appear you can refresh your index in settings tab.

Comment: This solution does not address the problem.

Comment: If ES doesn't apply proper index template you may refresh Kibana as much as you wish with no effect because Kibana takes the fields from ES.
So this answer is not answering anything.